# Why doesn't lock() throw an exception in case of a deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

Suppose we have the following code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex m;

void foo()
{
    m.lock();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th(foo);
    m.lock();
    th.join();
}
```

I know that this code contains a deadlock but I wonder about the following statement in the C++ Standard:

**30.4.1.2 Mutex types [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]**

> 6 The expression m.lock() shall be well-formed and have the following
>   semantics:
>
> [...]
>
> 12 Throws: system_error when an exception is required (30.2.2).
>
> 13 Error conditions:
>
> — (13.1) operation_not_permitted — if the thread does not have the
>   privilege to perform the operation.
>
> — (13.2) resource_deadlock_would_occur — if the implementation detects
>   that a deadlock would occur.
>
> — (13.3) device_or_resource_busy — if the mutex is already locked
>   and blocking is not possible.

As we can see, violating one of these rules should result in an exception:

**30.2.2 Exceptions [thread.req.exception]**

> 1 Some functions described in this Clause are specified to throw
>   exceptions of type system_error (19.5.7).
>   **Such exceptions shall be thrown if any of the function’s error conditions is detected** or a call to an operating system or other
>   underlying API results in an error that prevents the library function
>   from meeting its specifications

The code I provided surely contains a deadlock. Should the standard library throw an exception in such case then (because g++ and Visual C++ don't do it)? If not, why? Because from my point of view it seems that it either falls into 13.2 (resource_deadlock_would_occur) or 13.3 (device_or_resource_busy) category.

Comment: You tag this c++11 and c++14. Is it the same text in both specifications?

Comment: "if the implementation detects that a deadlock would occur" "if any of the function’s error conditions is detected"  But the detection is not required.

Comment: My guess is that the 'if ... is detected' language allows the compiler writer to argue that it's not detected (because they don't try to detect it), and thus they are not required to throw the exception.

Comment: The definition of a deadlock is two different locks, each owned by a different thread, and each trying to get the lock owned by the other. That's not the situation you have here.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Are you sure? How is it called then?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I don't think that's the definition. Fundamentally, "deadlock" means that no thread is making progress. How you achieve that is up to you.

Comment: The standardese says pretty plainly  "if detected". So maybe the condition is simply not detected by your implementation.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's the definition I remember. From [Wikipedia under "Necessary Conditions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions): "2. Hold and wait or resource holding: a process is currently holding at least one resource and requesting additional resources which are being held by other processes." That tells me that two different resources are required. P.S. I agree with you, the condition isn't necessarily required to be detected.

Answer (score 5):

You should program your code to handle deadlock exceptions, but do not rely on them to resolve deadlocks. There is no guarantee that deadlock exceptions will be thrown because they are not guaranteed to be detected. In other words, the implementation doesn't have to detect deadlocks, it just can, and that's how they are handled if they are found. It doesn't mean they will be found.

Deadlocking code is a logic error, don't write code that can deadlock.

Comment: I suspect that detecting all deadlocks is equivalent to solving the halting problem.

Comment: Well, technically not. A true "deadlock" can be detected. But localized aka partial deadlocks cannot always be detected. (e.g., two threads deadlock in regard to eachother, but there is one thread that renders the window/user interface that is not deadlocked.) Also, livelocks that have the same effect as deadlock cannot be detected.

Comment: Ok, that's about the `resource_deadlock_would_occur` error condition. But what about the `device_or_resource_busy` condition then? It doesn't say "if the implementation **detects**", it just says that "if the mutex is already locked and blocking is not possible". Am I right that the implementation **should** have such detections?

Comment: @FrozenHeart I think what it means is that if the mutex is already locked, the normal behaviour is to block the calling thread and wait its turn to lock the mutex, but if for any reason it can’t block the calling thread, it throws this exception instead.

Comment: @Mark Finding deadlocks is nothing more than finding cycles in a graph, which is a solved problem. Tarjan's algorithm can do it linearly in the number of nodes and edges.

Comment: @Voo actually no it isn't, given a mutex could be locked by one thread and unlocked by another, depending on the type of mutex.

Comment: @FrozenHeart There are strange situations where a thread cannot block.  These are not the kind of thing you'll experience in normal user-space C++ code.  In those cases, locking the mutex is specified to throw that error.

Answer (score 0):

30.4.1.2.1 [thread.mutex.class]

> 4. [ Note: A program may deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls lock() on that object. If the implementation can detect the deadlock, a resource_deadlock_would_occur error condition may be observed. —end note ]

And according to the pthread manual for [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html):

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, deadlock detection is not provided. Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock. If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behaviour results.

Remember, in the standard section you quoted:

> — resource_deadlock_would_occur — if the implementation detects that a deadlock would occur.

the key word is *if*.